# Sustituir todas las cadenas de un Excel por el año (anterior, actual o siguiente) y el mes (anterior, actual o siguiente) del sistema

Tags: python, string, date

Estoy tratando de sustituir -en **PYTHON**- en todas las queries que tengo en una hoja de un fichero Excel, las cadenas:

```
$annoAnterior-$mesAnterior
$annoActual-$mesAnterior
$annoActual-$mesActual
$annoActual-$mesSiguiente
$annoSiguiente-$mesSiguiente
```

**según el año y la fecha que tenga el sistema**.

Es decir, que si el sistema tiene fecha de 01/04/2021, que el resultado de esas sustitución quede como:

```
$annoAnterior-$mesAnterior   --> 2020-03
$annoActual-$mesAnterior   -->2021-03
$annoActual-$mesActual   --> 2021-04
$annoActual-$mesSiguiente   --> 2021-05
$annoSiguiente-$mesSiguiente   --> 2022-05
```

¿Alguna idea? Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Fernando, acá te dejo un código que te podría servir para modificar las fechas que quieres. Te recomiendo que leas la documentación del módulo de datetime, no necesitas instalarlo, ya viene dentro de python.

```
import datetime as dt


now = dt.datetime.now()

this_year = now.year #2021
this_month = now.month #4

last_year = this_year - 1 #2020
last_month = this_month - 1 #3

next_year = this_year + 1 #2022
next_month = this_month + 1 #5

today = dt.date.today() #2021-04-01

a = today.replace(year = last_year) #2020-04-01

b = today.replace(month = last_month) #2021-03-01

c = today.replace(year = next_year, month = next_month) #2022-05-01
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Ariel por tu respuesta. Consultaré dicha documentación. Por otro lado, para asignar esas fechas en todas las filas de la hoja1 de Excel que contengan queries debería hacer un FOR y recorrer todas las filas de la hoja Excel?

Comment: No se cómo es tu Excel, no podría decirte con seguridad. Pero te diría que sí, puede ser una opción. (Si la respuesta que te mande te sirvió y es correcta, acuérdate de marcarla como correcta, también me ayuda a mí eso :) ).